# Apache Spark,capability for time series analysis

Tags: apache-spark, time-series

I have just installed Apache Spark. I am interested to know if it has all the support for time series analysis, for example: AR, ARMA, Hidden Markov chains, ...
I can do everything in Python, but for huge time series it is extremely slow. Which libraries Spark uses?